Common notation for a unique morphism
Let $A,B$ be objects of a category. Assume that there is a unique morphism $A \to B$. Is there a notation for this morphism that has been used in at least one publication, or maybe is even common? Has $!_{A,B}$ been used somewhere? I have suggested, in a special case, $(A,B)$ here, but for general categories this will be confusing.
Assume in particular that $A$ is an initial object. In this case we want a notation that only depends on $B$. I have seen $!_B$ for the unique morphism to $B$. But I have also seen here this notation for the unique morphism into a terminal object, so in our case $!_A$ when $B$ is terminal. This is a collision. Has maybe $!_B$ and $!^A$ appeared somewhere? Or rather $!^B$ and $!_A$?
We can also just use $!$ (or nothing) in diagrams, but that is not sufficient for calculations where morphisms need names, hence the question.
I need a (commonly used) notation that is suitable in all three situations without any collision, and it should be a bit shorter for initial / terminal objects.
Background: When preparing some material on category theory I will explain the notation anyway but don't want to invent something that is not standard.

+1 from me: as a nitpick, surely, in the case when $A$ is an initial object, the morphism will depend on $A$ unless the category has a unique initial object?

True, but usually you fix an initial object, but the other objects can vary. This is why it's probably OK to omit it.

I don't think there is a standard notation. If there was, you probably wouldn't be asking this question. One publication also doesn't make something standard. So whatever notation you decide to pick, it's definitely a good idea to explain it.

OK, that's fine if it works for you in your teaching context. In some algebraic categories, I think we can name the morphisms from the initial object after the name of the initial object: so $1 : 1 \to G$ in the category of groups, or $0 : \mathbb{0} \to R$ in the category of rings (maybe with a subscript to identify the codomain). But if it's unique, it doesn't need a name!

@RobArthan But $0$ is not an initial object in the category of rings. $\mathbb{Z}$ is. (assuming you mean unital rings)

It needs a name in (linear) computations.

@Mark: I meant the category of rings that need not have a unit. As to Martin's latest comment, I understand that you need a name for use in computations and my last comment didn't help with that.

Let me offer a suggestion for notation for the unique morphism from an initial object and to a terminal object.
In general, a common notation for the mediating morphism to an $n$-ary product is $$\langle f_1, \ldots, f_n \rangle \colon X \to A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$$ where $\{ f_i \colon X \to A_i \}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$. Taking this convention to its logical limit, one notation for the mediating morphism to a terminal object is: $$\langle\rangle \colon X \to 1 \qquad\text{or}\qquad \langle\rangle_X \colon X \to 1$$
Similarly, a common notation for the mediating morphism from an $n$-ary coproduct is $$[f_1, \ldots, f_n] \colon A_1 + \cdots + A_n \to X$$ where $\{ f_i \colon A_i \to X \}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$. As before, this suggests the following notation for the mediating morphism from an initial object: $$[\,] \colon 0 \to X \qquad \text{or} \qquad [\,]_X \colon 0 \to X$$
While this isn't the most common notation for the mediating morphism from initial/to terminal objects (which I believe would be $!$), I think it is the clearest. It appears, for instance, in these lecture notes and in this paper, but I have certainly seen it in other references (cf. this book, which also uses this notation for terminal objects, but does not have a consistent notation for initial objects).

For unique morphisms between non-initial/terminal objects, I think both $!_{A, B} \colon A \to B$ and $A \leq B$ are reasonable and unambiguous notation. $!$ is often used to denote a unique morphism, while $A \leq B$ is often used in the context of thin categories, but more generally makes sense in the context of individual hom-sets. I am not sure I have actually seen $!_{A, B}$ used, but only because I think it is relatively uncommon to talk about non-thin categories with various unique morphisms for which the objects are not clear from context. In any case, I do not think any readers would find it surprising.

Awesome! That's a natural extension of your other answer. Can you perhaps remember the other places where you have seen this notation?

@MartinBrandenburg: yes, let me think about it and update my answer. Unfortunately I don't remember off-hand, and it's quite tricky to search for notation, but it should come back to me.

@MartinBrandenburg: I added another reference for the notation, and will update again when I remember others.

Great! And let me also say thank you for all the encyclopedic and historic knowledge that you have spread over the last years on category theory!
